# Is it possible to create mappings with parameters?

Tags: key-bindings

I have created a few mappings like so:

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>xyzABC   :call SomeFunc('ABC')<CR>
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>xyzDE    :call SomeFunc('DE')<CR>
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>xyzFoo18 :call SomeFunc('Foo18')<CR>
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>xyzBar22 :call SomeFunc('Bar22')<CR>
```

which works as desired.

I am now looking for a possibility to create a map-template that would allow me to remove the obvious redundant parts of my mappings, something like

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader> xyz? :call SomeFunc(?)<CR>
```

so that I could pass *any* value as parameter to `SomeFunc`.

Is there such a possibility?

Comment: You can use `input()` or `getchar()`. However it is probably more normal to use a command instead of a mapping for something that takes a parameter.

Comment: I agree with Peter's comment; commands are better suited to the job than mappings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @peter-rinckler said, it is probably easier to do it with a command:

```
command! -nargs=* Xyz :call SomeFunc(<q-args>)
```

Makes it possible to do (in normal mode)

```
:Xyz ABC
```

I don't really like the `input()` because you can't repeat those kinds of things easily.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Peter Rincker's comment, I have found the answer:

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader> xyz :call SomeFunc(input('Param: '))<CR>
```

Comment: Here is another example: `nnoremap <silent> <leader>tn :exe "tabn" nr2char(getchar())<cr>
`. The idea is to type `<leader>tn2` to navigate to tab 2.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php%3Fscript_id%3D2540), which aims at giving TextMate-like snippets to vim. It proved very helpful to me, anyway.